How to track revenue from Unity IAP purchase?
I use Uniyt IAP as a purchasing API and Adjust as an analytics API. I want to track a revenue from my purchases by sending the revenue data to the Adjust. But I can't find any API to get the revenue from a successful purchase in Unity IAP plugin.
Is there a way to get the revenue data from Uniyt IAP or integrate Unity IAP and Adjust with each other to automate this process?

What kind of revenue? If you are referring to your actual revenue, it should be 0 because you need to settle with the corresponding platform before getting your money. This also involves a series of issues such as discounts, exchange rates, taxes, etc. In short, Unity will not help you calculate these numbers. If you only refer to the price of the product, you should need to fill in the payout settings when adding products, so you can calculate it yourself.

I mean revenue, that  take into account deductions to the store. I can make an Adjust analytics integration with, for example, Adapty. And I will get all revenue correctly for any purchase for any platform. So far, I don't see any fundamental restrictions, that could prevent Unity IAP have same functionality. I just can't find it. And I want to get an information from people who have more experience with Unity IAP, then me, that Unity IAP really don't have such ability.

Actually it has. Unity IAP will automatically send transactions (including revenue) to Unity Analytics, so I guess they may not want to simply share these data with third-party APIs.

Yeah, sounds rational.

Well, you could simply try following:
Listen for successful purchase events in Unity IAP, then extract the relevant purchase data, such as the product ID and price and finally send the purchase data to Adjust using Adjust’s SDK. Whether it makes sense or not is an other question.
